# Bluetooth adapter for Sony digital photo frame

Tags: bluetooth

Which Bluetooth adapters will work with a Sony DPF-V1000N digital photo frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual states you need "DPPA-BT1".

[Here is a link](http://www.sony.co.uk/product/ddp-photo-printers/dppa-bt1) - That being said, the casing looks familiar to a cheap one I have laying around, so as it is USB and not a proprietary input (can't believe I am saying that on a Sony device!), it may be worth just getting a bog standard USB Bluetooth adapter and seeing if it works.